# Reloading models and helpers with Sinatra::Reloader

Tags: windows, sinatra, jruby, reload

I'm trying to automatically reload a Sinatra project in JRuby on Windows Vista/7. I'm using Sinatra::Reloader from Sinatra-contrib. Unfortunately, it only seems to work for controllers. Any changes to models and helpers aren't reloaded.

Am I using also_reload incorrectly or something?

Here's what my project looks like:
/app.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
require 'json'

class App < Sinatra::Application
  enable :sessions
  enable :logging
  register Sinatra::Reloader
  also_reload "models/*.rb"
  also_reload "helpers/*.rb"

  helpers do
    include Rack::Utils
    alias_method :h, :escape_html
  end
end

require_relative 'helpers/init'
require_relative 'models/init'
require_relative 'controllers/init'
```

/controllers/init.rb

```
enable :sessions

require_relative 'auth'
require_relative 'customer'
require_relative 'policy'
require_relative 'forms'
```

/helpers/init.rb

```
require_relative 'auth_helper'
require_relative 'customer_helper'
require_relative 'flash_helper'
require_relative 'form_helper'
require_relative 'policy_helper'
```

/models/init.rb

```
require 'lib/sqljdbc4.jar'
require 'sequel'
require 'logger'

Java::com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
url = 'foo'

DB = Sequel.connect(url)
DB.loggers << Logger.new($stdout)

Sequel.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.clear :all
end

files = [
:customer,
:customer_email,
:phone_number ]

files.each do |f|
  require_relative f.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Under current implementation of yours, let's say you change something in `helpers/auth_helper.rb`. This file gets reloaded but since the `helpers/init.rb` is unchanged, it won't be reloaded by sinatra-reloader and you won't see the changes. Have you tried `shotgun` gem?

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I'm using Windows. Shotgun won't work because there's no fork.